# Client unexpectedly shutdown

Tags: client-server, transactions

I am working on a .net rich client server application, the client call the server thru web service, what could happen if the client is suddently shutdown(connection closed) when it is calling the server? will the server be able to dectect this?
If the client is submitting a request to persist a set of data to server database, will the transaction still run?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it.  Make a web service call and then pull your internet cable.

Comment: It is hard to syn the hand movement with web service call which happen in ms :). What do you guys think should happen theoritically?